# Cannot detect obfuscator of the obfuscated DLL

Tags: deobfuscation, .net

I want to do a reverse-engineering of an obfuscated Unity DLL assembly, but de4dot doesn't work. It says "Unknown Obfuscator".
Also tried iMPROVE and it says that there is a 97% chance that it is a DotWall obfuscated assembly, but deobfuscation doesn't work!

Here is the DLL:
http://uploadboy.me/87n60oy2ifiw/Assembly-CSharp.zip.html

Can someone say how can I deobfuscate it? or at least which obfuscator has produced this DLL?

Answer (score 1):

It *is* **CodeWall**, strings are *not* encrypted, or really *slightly* (a simple XOR but nothing more complexe). You can use the ***IsLatin*** regex with De4Dot to clean the file as far as names are concerned.